# What tomatoes should I sucker, and which ones shouldn't I?

Tags: tomatoes

I'm familiar with tomatoes having two types, determinant, and indeterminant. Which ones are which, and how should I treat them differently?

Answer (score 2):

Determinant tomatoes are like a shrub.  Indeterminant more of a vine.  The latter needs guidance to keep from sprawling over the ground.  This indeterminant plant is great for vertical gardening to be able to grow even more tomatoes in less room.  Similar to everbearing and June bearing strawberries, June bearing produces a mass of tomatoes and then stops to do it again the next year[tomatoes](http://faq.gardenweb.com/discussions/2766765/what-is-the-difference-between-determinate-and-indeterminate-tomatoeshttp://)
, everbearing is more like the indeterminant vine-like tomatoe...produces until it dies from frost.

Comment: can you list them also?

Comment: Learn to look at a seed catalog - it's always in the listing for tomatoes, and there are FAR too many varieties for listing them all to be practical. You seem to have a very odd relationship with sources of data....

Comment: I guess you don't want to answer well enough, because determinate, and indeterminate is something I already knew about them.

Comment: Were you expecting someone to LIST all the different tomatoes that are determinate and then list all of those that are indeterminate?  From your question it sounded more of a general question than actually asking for a bunch of lists you can easily get from any catalog.  Would you like that in scientific nomenclature or common names?